# Migrate custom events created from Fabric into Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-fabric

My existing iOS app have custom events logged in Fabric to verify user actions. Now I migrated from fabric into firebase. All Crashlytics issues are shown in firebase Crashlytics. But custom events stored in fabric is not transferred to firebase events page. Will it automatically moved or we need to do it? Can anyone help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

new events added to firebase analytics takes [around a day](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?authuser=1&platform=android#view_events_in_the_dashboard) to update and reflected in events section, mean while you can debug your custom events and check in realtime for debug version check the following [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview)

Comment: I think this link shows new debugging events run via Firebase Crashlytics(Analytics.logEvent). I am asking about old custom events stored in Fabric using this method(Answers.logCustomEvent). This custom events can't see in debugging events page. I migrated app to firebase a week ago.